# Adding attribute on object during run time not happening

Tags: c#, object, attributes, typedescriptor

I try to add attributes on a certain object. This object can be int, string, List or whatever.

I try to use

`TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(object, attrList.ToArray());`

but this list of attributes do not show up when I do:

`object.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false)`

How come?

Best regards,

Gabriel Paulsson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this method does not dynamically change the metadata of the type, ultimately it only gives you back a [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) which includes the attributes you added.

You need to keep the return value of the AddAttributes method and query from there instead...

```
var myObject = { ... }

var typeDescriptionProvider = TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(myObject, attrList.ToArray());

var attributes = typeDescriptionProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(myObject).GetAttributes();
```

You can think of the type descriptor as a union of the type metadata itself (fixed), and any meta data you added at runtime (dynamic).

Comment: Gosh, I just lost 2 to 3 hours trying to dynamically add AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute, and that was my last shot.