# Why does not it work TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes of base class for System.Text.Json.Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
csTypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Base), new JsonDerivedTypeAttribute(typeof(Derived)));

var d = new Derived() { F1 = "111", F2 = "222" };
Base b = d;
var s = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(b);
Console.WriteLine(s);


//[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base
{
    public string F1 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string F2 { get; set; }
}
```

Serializer don't serialize derived type, output json:
{"F1":"111"}

but if uncommented [JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived))] that is serialized suceess:
{"F2":"222","F1":"111"}

Comment: Because `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes()` doesn't actually add attributes to the compile-time-generated attributes.  See [Adding attribute on object during run time not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10137762).  If you need to add `JsonDerivedTypeAttribute` metadata in runtime, see [How can I add JsonDerivedType without attributes in runtime in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77857543/3744182).  In fact your question looks to be a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: @dbc indeed this is the same question, thunks

Answer (score 2):

`TypeDescriptor` and reflection are two separate APIs; many serializers etc are based on the reflection model; the default `TypeDescriptor` model is *also* based on the reflection model (other implementations are available), but since the serializer library isn't asking `TypeDescriptor`: any tweaks you make there are entirely invisible and irrelevant to it, and it will only see things from reflection. The `TypeDescriptor` API is mainly used by UI binding frameworks (and even then: not always).